# How would I save a textView in Shared Preferences?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I want my app to save textView2 in shared preferences. This is the current shared preferences code I have that saves the state of a checkbox (checked/unchecked).

```
private boolean getFromSP(String key){
SharedPreferences bifrostPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return bifrostPrefs.getBoolean(key, false);
}
private void saveInSp(String key,boolean value){
SharedPreferences bifrostPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = bifrostPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean(key, value);
editor.commit();
}
```

I never really worked with shared prefrences before so I don't really know how would I create a new shared prefrence to save my textview2.

Comment: You can't store Views in the Shared Preferences. But you can save strings, so just use putString instead of putBolean and everything else works the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You can't.***

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.

From doc [Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Al-thought you can store value of TextView

```
//To get stored value
    private String getString(String key){
        SharedPreferences bifrostPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return bifrostPrefs.getString(key, "");
    }
```

..

```
//To Save value
    private void saveString(String key, String value){
         SharedPreferences bifrostPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("bifrostPrefs", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = bifrostPrefs.edit();
         editor.putString(key, value);
         editor.commit();
    }
```

---

How to use these methods

Put this code where you want to save TextVIew's value

```
//To save value of TextView
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(aTextView.getText())) {
    saveString("aTextView", aTextView.getText().toString());
}

//To Read and show into TextVIew
aTextView.setText(getString("aTextView"));
```

Comment: But where and how would I then call those 2 methods?

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I'm new to java so this still confuses me a lot but I hope it'll become easier with creating more and more apps.

Comment: yes... wish u all the best. you will be a good java/ android developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily save strings in Shared Preferences:

 If you are unsure how to use Shared Preferences, [this will be of great value to you.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

As to TextViews, How about saving `textView2.getText()` ? 
 `TextView.getText()` obviously returns the text TextView is displaying. If you need other TextView properties, [consult this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)